# Splitting a variable of product/tuple/pair type into its members in apply style

Tags: isabelle

let's assume we are working with a pair of type `('a × 'a)` and define a `fun` with pattern matching for it.

```
fun test :: "('a × 'a) ⇒ 'a ⇒ bool" where "test (a,b) c = True"
```

If I now have a variable `a_b` of type `('a × 'a)`, how can I replace it into its pair representation `(a,b)` in an apply style proof. For example, what is the best way to show the following lemma? How can I replace `test a_b c` with `test (a,b) c`?

```
lemma "test a_b c = True"
```

Does this also apply to pairs in the assumptions?

```
lemma "¬ test a_b c ⟹ flying_pigs"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using `cases`/`case_tac` on `a_b`?